# OpenSwan on Amazon EC2 - max number of retransmissions reached STATE_MAIN_I3. Possible authentication failure:

Tags: amazon-ec2, vpn, openswan

We are communicating with one of our clients over a VPN Tunnel.

Openswan tunnel was working perfectly fine before. Today we attached an Elastic IP to the server and rebooted. Since then the tunnel is not starting up.

These are the steps we have performed:

1. Asked the client to update our new IP at their end - DONE
2. Update the ipsec.config at our end - DONE (Here is the new file)

   ```
   nat_traversal=yes
   oe=off
   protostack=netkey
   interfaces="%defaultroute"       
   conn customer
           type=tunnel
           authby=secret
           left=%defaultroute
           leftid=52.24.154.45 <elastic-ip>
           leftsourceip=172.31.38.203 <internal-ip>
           leftnexthop=%defaultroute
           leftsubnet=172.31.0.0/16
           right=<client-public-ip>
           rightid=<client-public-ip>
           rightsubnet=<clients-subnet>
           phase2=esp
           phase2alg=3des-md5;modp1024
           ike=3des-md5;modp1024!
           ikelifetime=480m
           pfs=no
           auto=start
           rekey=yes
           keyingtries=%forever
   ```
3. ipsec.secrets - No modifications required

   ```
     include /var/lib/openswan/ipsec.secrets.inc
     <client-public-ip> 0.0.0.0 %any: PSK "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
   ```
4. [iptables -L](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fxe23.png)
5. [iptables -t nat -L](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CooHT.png)
6. ipsec auto --status

   `000 using kernel interface: netkey
   000 interface lo/lo ::1
   000 interface lo/lo 127.0.0.1
   000 interface lo/lo 127.0.0.1
   000 interface eth0/eth0 172.31.38.203
   000 interface eth0/eth0 172.31.38.203
   000 interface eth0/eth0 52.24.154.45
   000 interface eth0/eth0 52.24.154.45
   000 %myid = (none)
   000 debug none
   000

   000 virtual_private (%priv):
   000 - allowed 7 subnets: 10.0.0.0/8, 192.168.0.0/16, 172.16.0.0/12, 25.0.0.0/8, 203.201.213.0/24, fd00::/8, fe80::/10
   000 - disallowed 0 subnets: 
   000 WARNING: Disallowed subnets in virtual_private= is empty. If you have 
   000          private address space in internal use, it should be excluded!
   000

   000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=2, name=ESP_DES, ivlen=8, keysizemin=64, keysizemax=64
   000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=3, name=ESP_3DES, ivlen=8, keysizemin=192, keysizemax=192
   000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=6, name=ESP_CAST, ivlen=8, keysizemin=40, keysizemax=128
   000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=7, name=ESP_BLOWFISH, ivlen=8, keysizemin=40, keysizemax=448
   000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=11, name=ESP_NULL, ivlen=0, keysizemin=0, keysizemax=0
   000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=12, name=ESP_AES, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
   000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=13, name=ESP_AES_CTR, ivlen=8, keysizemin=160, keysizemax=288
   000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=14, name=ESP_AES_CCM_A, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
   000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=15, name=ESP_AES_CCM_B, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
   000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=16, name=ESP_AES_CCM_C, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
   000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=18, name=ESP_AES_GCM_A, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
   000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=19, name=ESP_AES_GCM_B, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
   000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=20, name=ESP_AES_GCM_C, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
   000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=22, name=ESP_CAMELLIA, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
   000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=252, name=ESP_SERPENT, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
   000 algorithm ESP encrypt: id=253, name=ESP_TWOFISH, ivlen=8, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=256
   000 algorithm ESP auth attr: id=1, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_HMAC_MD5, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=128
   000 algorithm ESP auth attr: id=2, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_HMAC_SHA1, keysizemin=160, keysizemax=160
   000 algorithm ESP auth attr: id=5, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_HMAC_SHA2_256, keysizemin=256, keysizemax=256
   000 algorithm ESP auth attr: id=6, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_HMAC_SHA2_384, keysizemin=384, keysizemax=384
   000 algorithm ESP auth attr: id=7, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_HMAC_SHA2_512, keysizemin=512, keysizemax=512
   000 algorithm ESP auth attr: id=8, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_HMAC_RIPEMD, keysizemin=160, keysizemax=160
   000 algorithm ESP auth attr: id=9, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_AES_CBC, keysizemin=128, keysizemax=128
   000 algorithm ESP auth attr: id=251, name=AUTH_ALGORITHM_NULL_KAME, keysizemin=0, keysizemax=0
   000

   000 algorithm IKE encrypt: id=0, name=(null), blocksize=16, keydeflen=131
   000 algorithm IKE encrypt: id=5, name=OAKLEY_3DES_CBC, blocksize=8, keydeflen=192
   000 algorithm IKE encrypt: id=7, name=OAKLEY_AES_CBC, blocksize=16, keydeflen=128
   000 algorithm IKE hash: id=1, name=OAKLEY_MD5, hashsize=16
   000 algorithm IKE hash: id=2, name=OAKLEY_SHA1, hashsize=20
   000 algorithm IKE hash: id=4, name=OAKLEY_SHA2_256, hashsize=32
   000 algorithm IKE hash: id=6, name=OAKLEY_SHA2_512, hashsize=64
   000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=2, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP1024, bits=1024
   000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=5, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP1536, bits=1536
   000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=14, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP2048, bits=2048
   000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=15, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP3072, bits=3072
   000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=16, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP4096, bits=4096
   000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=17, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP6144, bits=6144
   000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=18, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_MODP8192, bits=8192
   000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=22, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_DH22, bits=1024
   000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=23, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_DH23, bits=2048
   000 algorithm IKE dh group: id=24, name=OAKLEY_GROUP_DH24, bits=2048
   000

   000 stats db_ops: {curr_cnt, total_cnt, maxsz} :context={0,1,64} trans={0,1,3072} attrs={0,1,2048} 
   000

   000 "customer": 172.31.0.0/16===172.31.38.203[52.24.154.45]---172.31.32.1...203.201.209.98<203.201.209.98>===203.201.213.0/24; prospective erouted; eroute owner: #0
   000 "customer":     myip=172.31.38.203; hisip=unset;
   000 "customer":   ike_life: 28800s; ipsec_life: 28800s; rekey_margin: 540s; rekey_fuzz: 100%; keyingtries: 0 
   000 "customer":   policy: PSK+ENCRYPT+TUNNEL+UP+IKEv2ALLOW+SAREFTRACK+lKOD+rKOD; prio: 16,24; interface: eth0; 
   000 "customer":   newest ISAKMP SA: #0; newest IPsec SA: #0; 
   000 "customer":   IKE algorithms wanted: 3DES_CBC(5)_000-MD5(1)_000-MODP1024(2); flags=strict
   000 "customer":   IKE algorithms found:  3DES_CBC(5)_192-MD5(1)_128-MODP1024(2)
   000 "customer":   ESP algorithms wanted: 3DES(3)_000-MD5(1)_000; pfsgroup=MODP1024(2); flags=-strict
   000 "customer":   ESP algorithms loaded: 3DES(3)_192-MD5(1)_128
   000

   000 #2: "customer":4500 STATE_MAIN_I3 (sent MI3, expecting MR3); EVENT_RETRANSMIT in 33s; nodpd; idle; import:admin initiate
   000 #2: pending Phase 2 for "customer" replacing #0
   000`
7. tail /var/log/auth.log

   `Jan 11 20:10:57 ip-172-31-38-203 ipsec__plutorun: Starting Pluto subsystem...
   Jan 11 20:10:57 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: Starting Pluto (Openswan Version 2.6.38; Vendor ID OEvy\134kgzWq\134s) pid:27458
   Jan 11 20:10:57 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: LEAK_DETECTIVE support [disabled]
   Jan 11 20:10:57 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: OCF support for IKE [disabled]
   Jan 11 20:10:57 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: SAref support [disabled]: Protocol not available
   Jan 11 20:10:57 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: SAbind support [disabled]: Protocol not available
   Jan 11 20:10:57 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: NSS support [disabled]
   Jan 11 20:10:57 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: HAVE_STATSD notification support not compiled in
   Jan 11 20:10:57 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: Setting NAT-Traversal port-4500 floating to on
   Jan 11 20:10:57 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]:    port floating activation criteria nat_t=1/port_float=1
   Jan 11 20:10:57 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]:    NAT-Traversal support  [enabled]
   Jan 11 20:10:57 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: using /dev/urandom as source of random entropy
   Jan 11 20:10:57 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: ike_alg_register_enc(): Activating OAKLEY_AES_CBC: Ok (ret=0)
   Jan 11 20:10:57 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: ike_alg_register_hash(): Activating OAKLEY_SHA2_512: Ok (ret=0)
   Jan 11 20:10:57 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: ike_alg_register_hash(): Activating OAKLEY_SHA2_256: Ok (ret=0)
   Jan 11 20:10:57 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: starting up 1 cryptographic helpers
   Jan 11 20:10:57 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: started helper pid=27460 (fd:6)
   Jan 11 20:10:57 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: Using Linux 2.6 IPsec interface code on 3.13.0-36-generic (experimental code)
   Jan 11 20:10:57 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27460]: using /dev/urandom as source of random entropy
   Jan 11 20:10:57 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: ike_alg_register_enc(): Activating aes_ccm_8: Ok (ret=0)
   Jan 11 20:10:57 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: ike_alg_add(): ERROR: algo_type '0', algo_id '0', Algorithm type already exists
   Jan 11 20:10:57 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: ike_alg_register_enc(): Activating aes_ccm_12: FAILED (ret=-17)
   Jan 11 20:10:57 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: ike_alg_add(): ERROR: algo_type '0', algo_id '0', Algorithm type already exists
   Jan 11 20:10:57 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: ike_alg_register_enc(): Activating aes_ccm_16: FAILED (ret=-17)
   Jan 11 20:10:57 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: ike_alg_add(): ERROR: algo_type '0', algo_id '0', Algorithm type already exists
   Jan 11 20:10:57 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: ike_alg_register_enc(): Activating aes_gcm_8: FAILED (ret=-17)
   Jan 11 20:10:57 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: ike_alg_add(): ERROR: algo_type '0', algo_id '0', Algorithm type already exists
   Jan 11 20:10:57 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: ike_alg_register_enc(): Activating aes_gcm_12: FAILED (ret=-17)
   Jan 11 20:10:57 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: ike_alg_add(): ERROR: algo_type '0', algo_id '0', Algorithm type already exists
   Jan 11 20:10:57 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: ike_alg_register_enc(): Activating aes_gcm_16: FAILED (ret=-17)
   Jan 11 20:10:58 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: added connection description "customer"
   Jan 11 20:10:58 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: listening for IKE messages
   Jan 11 20:10:58 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: adding interface eth0/eth0 52.24.154.45:500
   Jan 11 20:10:58 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: adding interface eth0/eth0 52.24.154.45:4500
   Jan 11 20:10:58 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: adding interface eth0/eth0 172.31.38.203:500
   Jan 11 20:10:58 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: adding interface eth0/eth0 172.31.38.203:4500
   Jan 11 20:10:58 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: adding interface lo/lo 127.0.0.1:500
   Jan 11 20:10:58 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: adding interface lo/lo 127.0.0.1:4500
   Jan 11 20:10:58 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: adding interface lo/lo ::1:500
   Jan 11 20:10:58 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: loading secrets from "/etc/ipsec.secrets"
   Jan 11 20:10:58 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: loading secrets from "/var/lib/openswan/ipsec.secrets.inc"
   Jan 11 20:10:58 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: "customer" #1: initiating Main Mode
   Jan 11 20:10:58 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: "customer" #1: ignoring Vendor ID payload [FRAGMENTATION]
   Jan 11 20:10:58 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: "customer" #1: received Vendor ID payload [draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-02_n] method set to=106 
   Jan 11 20:10:58 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: "customer" #1: enabling possible NAT-traversal with method draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-05
   Jan 11 20:10:58 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: "customer" #1: transition from state STATE_MAIN_I1 to state STATE_MAIN_I2
   Jan 11 20:10:58 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: "customer" #1: STATE_MAIN_I2: sent MI2, expecting MR2
   Jan 11 20:10:58 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: "customer" #1: NAT-Traversal: Result using draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-02/03: i am NATed
   Jan 11 20:10:58 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: "customer" #1: transition from state STATE_MAIN_I2 to state STATE_MAIN_I3
   Jan 11 20:10:58 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: "customer" #1: STATE_MAIN_I3: sent MI3, expecting MR3
   Jan 11 20:12:01 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: initiate on demand from 172.31.38.203:0 to 203.201.213.58:80 proto=6 state: fos_start because: acquire
   Jan 11 20:12:08 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: "customer" #1: max number of retransmissions (2) reached STATE_MAIN_I3.  Possible authentication failure: no acceptable response to our first encrypted message
   Jan 11 20:12:08 ip-172-31-38-203 pluto[27458]: "customer" #1: starting keying attempt 2 of an unlimited number`

As you can see in the last few line, the problem is:

> "customer" #1: max number of retransmissions (2) reached
>   STATE_MAIN_I3.  Possible authentication failure: no acceptable
>   response to our first encrypted message

Can someone guide us in the right direction? We have tried almost every possible combination of Secret file and IPSec Config.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, if it relevant any more, but we are regularly experiencing similar errors on our VPN server (also hosted on AWS).

Normally restarting the services with these commands solves the problem:

- `/etc/init.d/ipsec restart`
- `/etc/init.d/xl2tpd restart`

But I don't know why this is happening in the first place. Sometimes the VPN tunnel collapses while being in use and only restarting it makes a connection possible again